# Help me understand whats wrong with my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I do this-

```
alert(anchor);
```

I get this-

> "[object HTMLLIElement]"

... ok, yep, it is the element I want. So I want to get that elements ID.

So I test it like this:

```
alert(anchor.attr("id"));
```

... but I don't get any alert, nothing. I must not be selecting an element. What am I doing wrong, what don't I understand?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Like your .attr syntax implies

Comment: yes! Looks like I found my problem. Everyone hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Also, you should really use the console to debug (`console.log` instead of `alert()`). Alerts are much harder. http://getfirebug.com or your built-in dev tools on your browser will really help.

Comment: How about some documentation for good ole JavaScript and no jQuery https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems:

- [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is a function jQuery objects have, you have a DOM element (you would need `$(anchor)` to use jQuery methods against the element).
- You don't need it anyway, the [`.id` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.id) will work (and be much faster), like this:

---

```
 alert(anchor.id);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning speed increase of `anchor.id`. I get so tired of seeing people write inefficient code just because they don't understand the overhead of frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `attr` is not a defined method or property on `anchor`. `anchor` is a raw HTML element object. It's not a jQuery object (I'm assuming you're using jQuery because you used the `attr` method).

To get the id, all you have to do is `anchor.id`. If you *really want* to use `attr`, you can do `jQuery(anchor).attr("id")`.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using jquery, then you need this:

```
alert($(anchor).attr("id"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `attr()` function is part of jQuery, but you're trying to get it from a plain DOM object. You either want to use `$(anchor)` (to wrap the element in jQuery) or call [`anchor.getAttribute("id")`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9) instead.